# SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager - Cannot disable Protocol in TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, tcp, sql-server-config-manager

I do have a problem with my SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager. All of my Yes/No answered option is not appearing. Is there any way to configure using command prompt? In Protocol tab, and IP Addresses tab, I cannot change all Yes/No options. Please refer to screenshots.[image: noYesNoOption]

[image: noYesNoOption2]

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot' ? is the drop down disabled? What do you mean 'not appearing'? They are certainly appearing in your screenshot. _what are you actually trying to do?_

Comment: what are your display options? are you using an extreme resolution? Multiple displays? Can you change things use keyboard navigation rather than mouse?

Comment: have you tried rebooting your machine and see if it can be changed after reboot?

Comment: Just had the same issue on a Windows 11 VM, Sergy's suggestion worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The following helped:
Launch the SQLServerManager11.msc from C:\Windows\SysWOW64